# How can I pass the user details on submit using React js

Tags: reactjs, button

I have two text fields id and name of the user . Below that a submit button .
How can I pass the user name and Id to handleSubmit() on click of the submit buton ?

```
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    <br/>
    <label>id : </label>
    <input type="text" name="userId" id="userId" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" oncClick={()=>this.handleSubmit()}value="Add 
    user"/>
```

Comment: Save the values to the state. And from handleSubmit, you just call `this.state.Name` to access the data you saved

Answer (score 1):

The value should be saved in the state of the component and updated `onChange`. Once `handleSubmit` is called you read the value from the state. `const { name } = this.state`

```
class form extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {value: ''};

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
     }

     handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
     }

     handleSubmit() {
         console.log(this.state.value)
     }

     render() {
       .....
     }
 }
```